# How to select one or other or no checkbox from dynamic table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a dynamic table. In each row, I've added two checkboxes, `buy` and `sell`, each with a `.checkboxClass` class. I want the user to be able to pick either `buy` or `sell`, but not both.

Here's my code so far:

```
$('input.checkboxClass').on('click', function() {
    $('input.checkboxClass').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

This works for only one row. As more rows are added, it fails. This is because the `checkboxClass` is repeated all throughout the table, meaning the script only lets you select one checkbox at a time.

Comment: Sounds like you need to traverse the DOM to find the other related checkbox. If you can also post your HTML structure, we can show you how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

I can't believe no one has suggested this so far. Your problem is a general misunderstanding of HTML. This is **not** what checkboxes are for. You should be using radio buttons:

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="buy" id="buy">
  <label for="buy">buy</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="sell" id="sell">
  <label for="sell">sell</label>
</div>
```

This will automate this functionality for you. No script required.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't show your HTML, I suppose you have something similar to:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Product 1 </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxClass" />Buy</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxClass" />Sell</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Product 2 </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxClass" />Buy</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxClass" />Sell</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Product 3 </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxClass" />Buy</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxClass" />Sell</td>        
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$('input.checkboxClass').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.checkboxClass').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true)
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yfmzorjp/)

*Note1: You may adjust the JavaScript code according to your HTML structure*

*Note2: I would rather use radio for this this use case, not checkboxes*

Comment: The question was actually edited! Question was "one or other checkbox checked OR none checked", so this is NOT radio buttons. Skafandri has an excellent answer that works. I really appreciate the help.