# jquery syntax for .on("change","input[name^=

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, bind, prop

### Project Focus

Toggle Checkbox(es)

### Special Requirement

Need to bind the new(dynamically) added `div.id container` that holds these checkboxes. **Note:** this `div.id` has been dynamically generated (client-side).

### Status

My [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpardon/zuganuu8/) successfully toggles between 1(one) or 0(none) checkboxes.

### The HTML

```
<div id="bind_id">
    <input type="checkbox" name="iso_01[]" class="setTitlePre1" value="L/R" />
    <label for name "iso_01" class="isoVar1">No.1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="iso_01[]" class="setTitlePre2" value="Alt" />
    <label for name "iso_01" class="isoVar2">No.2</label>
</div>
```

### Working Script

```
var checkboxes;
checkboxes = $("input[name^=iso_01]").change(function (e) {
checkboxes.not(this).prop("checked", false);
}
});
```

### Desired Result

I'm having trouble with syntax for updating `.click()` to `.on("click","input..."` see [Bound Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpardon/agbzLkne/)

### Updated Script

```
var checkboxes;
checkboxes = $("#bind_id").on("change", "input[name^=iso_01]", function (e) {
if (this.checked) {
checkboxes.not(this).prop("checked", false);
}
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select one or other or no checkbox from dynamic table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949700/how-to-select-one-or-other-or-no-checkbox-from-dynamic-table)

Comment: @royhowie Disagree. I reviewed this discussion. Researched a number of them before posting my own. I needed to understand the syntax for writing this sort of feature for my checkboxes. There is a larger picture, but my specific question was clearly and concisely answered within less than 3 minutes by karthikr. I do appreciate your insights as well though. I had considered radio buttons, but I didn't see that they served the `any, all or none` feature I was looking for from checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is,

```
checkboxes = $("#bind_id").on
```

is not doing what you think it is doing. It is *not* storing all the matched nodes.

Try this instead:

In the callback, change

```
checkboxes.not(..)
```

to

```
$('input[name^=iso_01]').not(this).prop("checked", false);
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agbzLkne/1/)

Or if they are loaded dynamically, you can use `$('#bind_id').find('input[name^=iso_01]')`

Answer (score 1):

This is not what checkboxes are for. You should be using radio buttons:

```html
<input type="radio" name="example" value="1" id="1">
<label for="1">one</label>
<input type="radio" name="example" value="2" id="2">
<label for="2">two</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `checkboxes` is the `#bind_id` element, not the checkboxes. You would need to [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the children from that element, to get the child checkbox elements.

### Working Example:

```js
var wrapper;
wrapper = $("#bind_id").on("change", "input[name^=iso_01]", function (e) {
    if (this.checked) {
        wrapper.find("input[name^=iso_01]").not(this).prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bind_id">
    <input type="checkbox" name="iso_01[]" class="setTitlePre1" value="L/R" />
    <label for name "iso_01" class="isoVar1">No.1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="iso_01[]" class="setTitlePre2" value="Alt" />
    <label for name "iso_01" class="isoVar2">No.2</label>
</div>
```